# Writing a chunk of a file to a socket in Swift

Tags: swift, socket

I'm writing a chunk of a file from an offset to a socket.

This is my implementation and it's working OK from my tests.

Any comments or speed improvements?

```
private func sendChunk(_ source: Int32, _ target: Int32, _ offset: off_t, _ count: UInt64) -> Int64 {
    let bufferSize:Int = 1024
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
    var writed:UInt64 = 0
    var read:Int = 0
    while true {
        let remaining = Int(count - writed)
        if remaining < bufferSize {
            read = pread(source, &buffer, remaining, offset + Int64(writed))
        } else {
            read = pread(source, &buffer, buffer.count, offset + Int64(writed))
        }
        guard read > 0 else {return Int64(read)}
        var writeCounter = 0
        while writeCounter < read, writed < count {
        let writeResult = write(target, &buffer + writeCounter, read - writeCounter)
            guard writeResult > 0 else {return Int64(writeResult)}
            writeCounter = writeCounter + writeResult
            writed += UInt64(writeCounter)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type annotations in

```
let bufferSize:Int = 1024
var read:Int = 0
```

are not necessary, this can be simplified to

```
let bufferSize = 1024
var read = 0
```

The variable names can be improved: 
`read` is not ideal since there is a system call
`read()` with the same name. The past participle of "to write" is
"written", not "writed", a better variable name might be `totalBytesWritten` since it contains the accumulated number of
bytes written to the target file.

The conversion to `Int` in

```
    let remaining = Int(count - writed)
```

can overflow on a 32-bit architecture. If the number of bytes to
read is computed as

```
    let readAmount = Int(min(count - totalBytesWritten, Int64(bufferSize)))
```

instead then it can not overflow and only one call to `pread()`
is needed.

There is a bug in

```
        writed += UInt64(writeCounter)
```

which should be

```
        writed += UInt64(writeResult)
```

otherwise the number of bytes written is added multiple times to 
the total counter if multiple `write()` calls were necessary
(and then `count - writed` can crash).

With the outer loop

```
while true { ... }
```

`pread()` is called once more if all data has been copied. That can be
avoided by changing the outer loop to

```
while totalBytesWritten < count { ... }
```

Then also the logic becomes clearer and the condition in

```
    while writeCounter < read, writed < count { ... }
```

can be simplified.

Your function can only return `0` (on success) or `-1` (on error),
therefore the return type `Int64` makes no sense.

One possibility would be to change the return type to `Bool` to indicate
success or failure. Another possibility is to return the total number
of bytes copied in the success case (which can be less than the `count`
parameter if end-of-file was encountered), or `nil` on failure.
Yet another possibility is to `throw` an error, that allows to report
details on the problem to the caller.

I would not use empty external parameter names (`_`), a call

```
sendChunk(source: sfd, target: dfd, offset: 2, count: 5)
```

is more descriptive than

```
sendChunk(sfd, dfd, 2, 5)
```

The `offset` parameter could be defined with an default value zero.

Putting it all together the function could look like this:

```
func sendChunk(source: Int32, target: Int32, offset: off_t = 0, count: UInt64) -> UInt64? {

    let bufferSize = 1024
    var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)

    var totalBytesWritten: UInt64 = 0
    while totalBytesWritten < count {
        let readAmount = Int(min(count - totalBytesWritten, UInt64(bufferSize)))
        let bytesRead = pread(source, &buffer, readAmount, offset + off_t(totalBytesWritten))
        guard bytesRead > 0 else {
            return bytesRead == 0 ? totalBytesWritten : nil
        }

        var bytesWritten = 0
        while bytesWritten < bytesRead {
            let amount = write(target, &buffer + bytesWritten, bytesRead - bytesWritten)
            guard amount > 0 else {
                return nil
            }
            bytesWritten += amount
        }
        totalBytesWritten += UInt64(bytesWritten)
    }

    return totalBytesWritten
}
```

Possible *speed* improvements: Most time will be spent in the read/write
system calls. One thing that you can do is to increase the
buffer size.